# How to auto generate Junit test cases for Entity classes and DTO's in spring project

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit4

I'm working on a spring boot project,
i have many Entity classes and DTO classes with mostly getters and setters in it.

is there any way or plugin that create junit test cases for all the Entity and DTO classes. Just to improve test coverage.

currently using this frameworks Spring boot, Hibernate, Junit 4.12, Mockito. Java 1.8, intellij IDE.
EX: 
`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "xyz")
public class Xyz {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    public Integer id;

    @Column(name = "col1")
    public Integer col1;

    @Column(name = "col2")
    public Integer co2;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    };`
```

Comment: I realize it's not exactly what you asked, but if your goal is to improve test coverage, you might also consider excluding those Entity/DTO classes from coverage metrics, assuming they really are just full of getters and setters.

Comment: Yes, there are libraries for that: pojo-tester, equalsverifier, openpojo

Comment: @user3521432 Added one solution it helps to increase code coverage along with unit testing of entities/DTO classess.

Answer (score 7):

**Never ever write tests for entities and DTOs.** Usually They do not have any business logic you could test (unless something is really wrong with your design).

Better to exclude them from your test metrics than trying to make tests for making tests.

Comment: They don't have any business logic. I need it for only test coverage. As per our company noms line coverage of project should be greater then 80.

Comment: This doesn't change the fact that making higher test coverage via tests for pojos doesn't make much sense anyway. Better if you could focus on improving coverage by testing business logic instead.

Comment: This reminds me a situation where a developer gets money for the amount of code he has written. He will write tons of "spagetti code" to meet company policies and get better salary, but this doesn't make "spagetti code" a good thing.

Comment: No one ever ran into a case where equals and hashCode where implemented differently causing HashMaps to run wild? Even with Lombok I had sometimes cyclic references between classes causing toString() to result in a StackOverflowError. Just saying that sometimes basic (non-business) logic needs testing as well.

Comment: Entities are where most of your business logic should be actually. This is a big misconception in the spring community.

Answer (score 0):

For test case coverage you can do it like below , But I don't think so its good way, But it helps to increase code coverage:

```
public class XyzTest {

    public Xyz crateTestSuite(){
      return new Xyz();
     }

    @Test
    public void testGetId() {
     Integer id= 0;
     Xyz xyz =null;
     xyz = crateTestSuite();
     id = xyz.getId()

    }

    @Test
    public void setId(Integer id) {
     Integer id= 0;
     Xyz xyz =null;
     xyz = crateTestSuite();
     xyz.setId(id)
    } 
}
```